# Implement Cloneable using Scala

Tags: scala

How to use cloneable interface in Scala to clone the class object?

This code will tell, how cloneable works in Scala and it worked for me.

```
 class CloneableClass extends scala.Cloneable {
   def myMethod: Unit = println("Inside :"+this.getClass)
   override def clone(): CloneableClass =super.clone().asInstanceOf[this.type]
}

class CloneableDemo  {
  val cc = new CloneableClass
  val cc1 = cc.clone()
  cc1.myMethod
}

object CloneObject extends App {
  val cd = new CloneableDemo
}

Output: Inside : class CloneableClass
```

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like you answer your own question in the question itself. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

Also, instead of writing an implementation of `clone` method in every class you can create a generic trait:

```
trait TypedCloneable[SelfType <: Object] extends scala.Cloneable {
  self: SelfType =>
  override final def clone(): SelfType = super.clone().asInstanceOf[SelfType]
}
case class TestClass1(x: Int) extends TypedCloneable[TestClass1]
case class TestClass2(x: Int, y: String) extends TypedCloneable[TestClass2]

val testClass1: TestClass1 = TestClass1(1)
val testClass2: TestClass2 = TestClass2(1, "y")
val testClass1Clone: TestClass1 = testClass1.clone()
val testClass2Clone: TestClass2 = testClass2.clone()
```